# In App Search in wp7 app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've a listbox which has many items. I'm trying to create a search bar so that a user can type in what he is looking for and my listbox displays only those items relevant to what the user has typed in textbox. I'm new to wp7

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `MVVM` for proper `Layout` updating. Then use additional property and bind it to `TextBox`. When property was updated - rise another property changed event to update `ListBox` (`FirePropertyChanged("FooList");` in snippet).

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

in `ViewModel`:

```
public string SearchCriteria
{
     get
     {
         return searchCriteria;
     }
     set
     {   
         serchCriteria = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("SearchCriteria");
         RaisePropertyChanged("FooList");
     }
}
private List<Foo> fooList;

public List<Foo> FooList
{
    get 
    {
       return fooList.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchCriteria)); 
    }
}
```

in `Xaml`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="searchText" Text={Binding SearchCriteria, Mode=TwoWay} />
<ListBox x:Name="elementsList" ItemsSource={Binding FooList, Mode=TwoWay}>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   ...
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

Some help links for better understanding `MVVM` pattern:

- [Windows Phone Mango: Getting Started with MVVM in 10 Minutes](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Mango-Getting-Started-with-MVVM-in-10-Minutes)
- [MVVM in real life Windows Phone applications Part1](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/MVVM-in-real-life-Windows-Phone-applications-Part1)

Comment: Thank You for your reply. But sorry, I didn't understand the binding to texbox and rise the property changed even. Can you please help

Comment: Thanks a lot. The article helped me out. Trying the search feature now!!

Comment: @user1538895 If this solved your problem you can accept the answer, if not - please, describe issue more precisely and we will deal with it.

Comment: Thank You very much. The problem got solved. I even went through MVVM articles. I would like to rate your answer but can't as my reputation is less than 15. I'm new to stackoverflow :(

Comment: @user1538895 You can accept answer without updating it. Just press on check mark under votes. Accepting answers also will increase your rate.